# Image Displaying in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a clip art image appear inside of a canvas in JavaScript and for some reason the clip art is not appearing on top of the rectangle I am drawing as a border for it and I have no clue how to make them both appear.  The rectangle is showing up just not the picture. Am I not allowed to put both in a canvas? Do I need to layer two canvases? Am I just coding this incorrectly? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<canvas id = "myCanvas" width = "400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
var r = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var rec = r.getContext("2d");
rec.strokeStyle = "black";
rec.rect(20,20,300,300);
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function()
{
    rec.drawImage(img,30,30);
}
img.src = "monkey-face-cartoon.png";
rec.stroke();
function monkeyMove(){
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the image isn't being loaded properly, and therefor `img.onload` isn't being called. I swapped out the src for a data-uri and it rendered just fine. Where abouts are you getting the image from?

Comment: The image is from my personal computer, saved to my desktop, I just did not put the directory up.  What is a data-uri?

Comment: A data uri is a form of encoding, in this case encoding an image as a string. Check [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLdeaG?editors=1010) which has your code but showing the stack overflow logo. The data URI is the part starting with `data:image/png;base64`. You can read more about them [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)

Comment: And for serving the image - to serve assets from your filesystem they need to be served from a server, not from `file://~Desktop/index.html`. The easiest way to do this if you have python is running `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` (more on this [at 2ality](http://www.2ality.com/2014/06/simple-http-server.html)). This should be run in the same directory as the `index.html` file and the `monkey-face-cartoon` file

Comment: That did not work at all, it just tried to display the uri code and then did not display an image.

Comment: The codepen? Which browser are you using? It should work in any modern-ish browser